# Distribute an app in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, store

How can I distribute an app in windows 8.1 or higher as a limited extent inside a company?

I made the next steps but I failed:

> • I created an app and uploaded the appxupload arquives
>
> • I defined the visibility Hide this app and stop selling
>
> • I generated promotional codes and I distributed them
>
> • I could exchanged this codes but I couldn’t downloaded them

I also changed the visibility method to: Hidden the app in the store. If customers have a direct link to the app description, they can download the app with exceptions: windows 8 and windows 8.1. But this only solve the problem in windows 10 devices.

Which are the correct steps to publish an app in windows store to windows 8.1 operating system in a limited extent? Or, if i can do it in the store, how can I do it?

Thank you